# Random Numbers Test (Histogram)

Tags: java, methods, random, compiler-errors, histogram

I'm brand new to Java coding i'm trying to create a histogram with the following methods that were given to me. The comments are the instruction to each of our method that we will later use to create a main method and print a histogram. I have got up to method 3 and was able to compile everything fine but i'm not sure if i'm doing them right, I just know that they are compiling correctly up to method 4. I just don't know what to do for method 5.
    /* 
    Method 1:
    Find the maximun value in an array
    */

```
public static int max(int[]arr){
    int maxValue = arr[0];
    for ( int i=1; i < arr.length; i++ ){
        if (arr[i] > maxValue){
            maxValue = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

/* 
Method 2:
Compute a random integer in the range [a..b)
*/

public static int randomInteger(int a, int b){;
    int randomNum;

    randomNum = a+(int)(Math.random() * ((b-a)+1));
    return randomNum;
}

/* 
Method 3:
Draw a Simple histogram of the array arr.
*/

public static void drawHistogram(int[] arr){
    for ( int i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ){
        System.out.print((i*10+1)+"-"+(i*10+10)+":"+"\t");

        for (int j=0; j<arr[i]; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.println();
    }
}

/* 
Method 4:
Compute num random integers in the range [0..range) and put the frequency in arr[]
*/

public static void doSingleTest(int[] arr, int num, int range){
    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        int random = randomInteger(0,range);
        arr[random]++;
    }
}

/* 
Method 5:
Compute num pairs of random integers in the range [0..range) and put the frequency in arr[]
*/

    public static void doPairsTesting(int[] arr, int  num, int range){

   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,6,11,7};
    System.out.println("method1 = "+ max(test));
    System.out.println("method2 = "+randomInteger(1,20));
    drawHistogram(test);
    doSingleTest(test,1,5);
    System.out.println("method4 = "+Arrays.toString(test));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fault design `int random = int randomInteger(range);` I think you need to read [docs abot java basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/).

I fixed method4 in next way:

```
public static void doSingleTest(int[] arr, int num, int range){
    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        int random = randomInteger(0,range);
        arr[random]++;
    }
}
```

For testing your methods, use next main method, it prints results to console or you can use Debugger in your IDE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,6,11,7};
    System.out.println("mathod1 = "+ max(test));
    System.out.println("mathod2 = "+randomInteger(1,20));
    drawHistogram(test);
    doSingleTest(test,1,5);
    System.out.println("mathod4 = "+Arrays.toString(test));

}
```

And at last your method 5 must to return value of needed type or be **void**:

```
public static void doPairsTest(int[] arr, int num, int range){

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help on method 4. And yes I really do need to read more on basics but I just got lost and that I couldn't even understand the book as well. I guess it's easier to learn from someone with explanation. 

Also Im getting a error on the main method:
RandomNum.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.println("mathod4 = "+Arrays.toString(test));
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class RandomNum
1 error
Process javac exited with code 1

Comment: I think you need to add next line of code to your **imports** for class : `import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 0):

For computing random integers, you might want to consider using the `Random` class. Here is some documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

You can do this by declaring a Random object inside your class like this:

```
static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
```

And then within each of your methods, you can use `randomGenerator.nextInt(n)`, where n will be the end of the range you want random numbers to be included. (exclusive of n, starting with 0).

For method 4, you probably want to set the return type to be an array. And then you can either leverage this randomGenerator, or given your current code, you'd have to pass in two parameters to your `randomInteger` method.

For method 5, you can simply use your doSingleTest method and then divide the entries of your array by 2 before returning the array. This works because if you find two 3s, your doSingleTest would have a frequency of 2 at the appropriate position. And dividing this by 2 would give you the number of pairs. Also you don't have to worry about odd numbers because the `int` type in Java simply drops remainders.

I also just noticed that you did not set a return type for method 5, so go ahead and set that to be `int[]`

And use a `public static void main(String[] args)` method to test your methods.

Comment: I just updated the code and I have a working method 4 now. I just don't know what to do on method 5 and even how to start it. Also Im getting an error on my main method for the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

For method 5, are you referring to the dopairtest? In case so here is how I solved that:

static void doPairsTest(int[] arr3, int num2, int range3){

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < num2 ; i++) {
        int rand2 = randomInteger(0, range3);
        int rand3 = randomInteger(0, range3);
        int randomPair = (rand2 * 10) + rand3 ;
        System.out.println(randomPair);
        arr3[randomPair] ++ ;
    }   
}
```

As you can see I just declared and assigned randomly generated values from my previous method into rand2 and rand 3 and then I added the two of them so they add up to a double digit.

Did you find out how to do the histogram? I am very confused on how to plot it based on the numbers and frequencies we generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void drawHistogram(int[] arr){
        int n=0;
        for (int i=1;i<=99;i++)
            if (arr[i]>n)
                n=arr[i];
        for (;n>0;n--)
        {
            String r="  ";
            for (int i=0;i<=99;i++)
            if (n<=arr[i])
            {
                System.out.print(r+"*");
                r="  ";
            }
            else
                r+="   ";
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```